# Angular - Wait for service to complete before navigating

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-services

I am trying to set data in a service and then navigate once the data has populated in the service, I am having a timing issue where the page is navigating before the service has been able to populate.

I have the following code in a service

```
addToken(token) {
  this.cookieService.set( 'token', token );
}
```

and the following code when a button is clicked:-

```
this.token.addToken(res);
this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
```

Once the router is triggered the /admin page triggers an endpoint with the following headers:-

```
authHttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token.getToken(),
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
});
```

The getToken() function just receives the token from the cookie:-

```
getToken() {
  return this.cookieService.get('token');
}
```

How can I ensure the addToken() has finished before the router navigation is triggered.

I know I can achieve it with a setTimeout, but I really don't like doing that.

I would prefer to have some form of observable or a way of seeing that the token in not equal to null or empty before the navigation router is triggered.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: did you think about using promises?

Comment: What is asynchronous in your code?

Comment: This pattern seems strange, usually you navigate first and then load data. Does the data change the place you navigate to or what is displayed when you navigate?

Comment: Strange because your function when you click and the two calls are synchronous... (except the navigate function itself)

Answer (score 5):

Return an observable so that you can subscribe to it and wait for the service to end its thing, and filter the response to cancel when the token is falsy.

```js
addToken(token) {
  this.cookieService.set( 'token', token );
  return of(token);
}
```

```js
this.token.addToken(res)
.pipe(filter(res => !!res))
.subscribe(() => {
  this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
});
```

Comment: @Faisal make your own answer instead of modifying mine please. If I didn't talk about promises, I have my reasons.

Comment: I edited yours because I thought there was no need to add another answer, anyways forget it.

Comment: This works very well thank you, but I get the following error, Shadowed name: 'res' (no-shadowed-variable). Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: @AngularDeveloper `filter(response => !!response)` will do

Comment: @Faisal promises don't allow piping and filtering empty results. And even if it did, instead of returning `new Promise`, you could have used the resolve method of the promise prototype, which is clearer and easier to read : `return Promise.resolve(token)`.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get the difference with the original code. If `this.cookieService.set( 'token', token );` is synchronous, then no need for observable. If it async - then you should wait for cookieService.set to resolve.

Comment: `I would prefer to have some form of observable or a way of seeing that the token in not equal to null or empty before the navigation router is triggered`. This is what I added, as per the author's requirement.

Comment: OK, so currently it is no more than ```this.token.addToken(res);
if (res) this.router.navigate(['/admin']);```

Comment: @udalmik yes it is.

Comment: Could you describe the difference in answer. I really don't see it, as whole execution is synchronous now. Could be useful for others also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177945/discussion-between-udalmik-and-trichetriche).

Comment: The difference is the use of an Observable, as requested. There's really no difference between your comment and my answer : I answered what the author asked. I did so because most of the time, OPs don't provide their whole code in their answer. So I only deal with what I'm provided with : in this case, he wanted something, I gave him the answer. He probably does something else (or not), but now he has all the cards to chose from.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, this works fine locally, but when I push the code up to a server I am getting the same issue as before. I will update my question to show more code.